# How to have a number of inputs based on an input number

Tags: python

So my goal is to create a program that tells the total price of building a fence but it wants to do multiple jobs at once so I need an input to tell me how many inputs I need to calculate the total price. (I am very new to Python so my bad if I didn’t word this very well)

I couldn’t figure it out at all so far all I have is just the variables set to my price then I also have the tax variable set.

```
> LF = 25
> LAB = 15
> TAX = .0825
> JOB = input(‘how many linear feet? :’)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prompt for the number of inputs, then use `input` in a list comprehension. You can manipulate the resulting list as needed.

```
>>> n = int(input("How many? "))
How many? 5
>>> [input() for _ in range(n)]
3
6
1
2
5
['3', '6', '1', '2', '5']
```

In practice, you probably want to verify that input succeeded and `n` is within a valid range before continuing to the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corectly are you looking something like this:

```py
LF = 25
LAB = 15
TAX = 0.0825

num_jobs = int(input('How many jobs do you want to calculate? :'))

total_cost = 0

for job in range(num_jobs):
    linear_feet = float(input(f'Enter the linear feet for job {job + 1}: '))
    
    job_cost = (linear_feet * LF) + LAB

    total_cost += job_cost + (job_cost * TAX)

print(f'Total cost for {num_jobs} jobs: ${total_cost:.2f}')
```